# Probability of Ace and King of same suit and probability of quads

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, card-games

Compute the probability that a
hand of 13 cards contains
(a) the Ace and King of at least one suit;
(b) all 4 of at least 1 of the 13 denominations.

Below, you will see the work that I had for this problem, yet I was told is completely wrong. The solution used the inclusion-exclusion formula, was long and drawn out, and seemingly much over the scope of the class. The answers I got for both were within 0.01 of the answers provided. What was wrong with my answer?

[image: Work for both parts of the problem]

Comment: You are double-, triple-, and, in the first problem's case, quadruple-counting some hands.

Comment: What's your logic for multiplying by $\binom{13}{2}$ and $\binom{13}{4}$ in the two calculations?

Comment: @A.J. In the 1st problem, the original poster is (nicely but wrongly) deciding that first you have to choose which $~2~$ of the $~13~$ cards will be the AK-same-suit combo, and then you compute the probability of that happening.  The only flaw in the analysis is captured in the comment of Brian Moehring.  For example, suppose that the first two cards are AK-Hearts, and the second two cards are AK-Spades.  This gets counted twice: once when the AK-combo is in positions 1,2 and once when the AK-combo is in positions 3,4.  So, you are counting the same 13 card deal **twice**.  This is wrong.

Comment: @user2661923 I was clear on the overcounting, just not on the two binomial coefficients, but I get them now. I think if he'd started the calculations with those two I might have made sense of his reasoning.

Comment: @A.J. I figured.  Most of the comment was addressed to the OP himself.